# Java annoying syntax error

Tags: java, syntax-error

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to make an lvling system. Hers my code so far:

```
    import java.util.*;
class Player
{
    private String Name;
    private int Level;
    private int EXP;
    int NextGoaltoLvl = 1000;

    public Player(String n, int lvl, int xp) 
    {
        Name = n;
        Level = lvl;
        EXP = xp;
    }
    public void printStats()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " +Name);
        System.out.println("Level: " +Level);
        System.out.println("Exp: " + EXP);
    }
    public void addLevel(int addlvl)
    {
        Level += addlvl;
        System.out.println("Congratulations,"+ Name +",you have leveled up to " + Level + "!");
    }
    public void addExp(int num)
    {
        EXP += num; 
        if (EXP == NextGoaltoLvl)
        {
            addLevel(1); NextGoaltoLvl += 1000; EXP = 0; 
        }
    }
}
public class MainC 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Player Player01 = new Player("kert109",1,0);
        for (int i = 0; i >= 10000; i++)
        {
            Player01.addExp(1);
        }
        Player01.printStats();
    }
}
```

`Player01.printStats();`
I still having an error here. Says: Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody.

I have no idea whats wrong. Help? I have check ever "{" and "}". I have cleaned to code too. (Using Eclipse.)

Comment: your problem starts at line 29, you close the function, then start a wihle loop.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To help us answer your question, please provide what you've tried so far and only the specific parts of your code that you're having issues with.

Comment: Check what I said after the code.

Comment: Nvm I just ran and it fix it self. Eclipse error? xD Ty for the help with the other errors.

Comment: Voted to close as too localized.  Nobody else is going to helped by this Q & A ... especially since the Q has been edited so that the answers no longer make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
public void addExp(int num)
{
    EXP += num;
}
while (true)
{   
    if (EXP == NextGoaltoLvl)
    {
        addLevel(1); NextGoaltoLvl += 1000; EXP = 0; 
    }
}
```

(an **infinite loop**? **outside all function code**? **compile error** + **logic error**)

I think you want

```
public void addExp(int num)
{
    EXP += num;

    if (EXP == NextGoaltoLvl)
    {
        addLevel(1); NextGoaltoLvl += 1000; EXP = 0; 
    }
}
```

(increment level if XP reaches new level XP)

A. R. S points out another serious issue with your for loop.

Instead of

```
for (int i; i >= 10000; i++)
    {
```

You want

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
    {
```

or just

```
 Player01.addExp(10000);
```

If what you want to do is to **add 10000 XP** to the player

Comment: I think I do. :o I didn't think about that. *FacePalm* I script Lua too much. xD

Answer (score 1):

Two errors I see:

1.
Near `addExp`, there is a `while` loop outside of the method, which is a syntax error. What's the purpose of this loop anyhow? It's an infinite loop without any `break`s or `return`s in its body - is it actually supposed to go on forever?

2.

```
for (int i; i >= 10000; i++)
{
    Player01.addExp(1);
}
```

You forgot to initialize `i` here. Although, this loop doesn't make sense, your condition asks if `i` is *greater* than something else and yet you increment it on each iteration (`i++`). What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I just fixed both before you I looked at this. xD

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop isn't in a method. Here's a revised addExp method.

```
public void addExp(int num)
{
    EXP += num;

    if (EXP == NextGoaltoLvl)
    {
        addLevel(1); NextGoaltoLvl += 1000; EXP = 0;
    }
}
```

You're also not initializing `i` in your main method. It's also important to note that `i >= 10000` will always return false. Your for loop should probably be revised to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    Player01.addExp(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put the while loop inside of the method addExp and initialize i to 0 in one of your for loops

```
 public void addExp(int num)
{
    EXP += num;
    while (true)
    {   
        if (EXP == NextGoaltoLvl)
        {
            addLevel(1); NextGoaltoLvl += 1000; EXP = 0; 
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Player Player01 = new Player("kert109",1,0);
    for (int i=0; i >= 10000; i++)
    {
        Player01.addExp(1);
    }
    Player01.printStats();
}
```

Comment: while loop + non executing for

Comment: his question was how to get rid of the syntax errors and my code did that. Why was this down voted? @KarthikT

Comment: Downvoted 3 straight to the point answers.

Comment: +rep for being straight forward

Answer (score 0):

1) For loop has an error because you have initiated `int i` without specifying it's initial value.

```
for( int i = yourInitialValue; i >=  10000; i++ )
```

2)

```
public void addExp(int num)
    {
        EXP += num;
    }
    while (true)
    {   
        if (EXP == NextGoaltoLvl)
        {
            addLevel(1); NextGoaltoLvl += 1000; EXP = 0; 
        }
    }
```

while loop is outside your addExp method. Where you might want it to be:

```
public void addExp(int num){

        EXP += num;

        while (true)
        {   
            if (EXP == NextGoaltoLvl)
            {
                addLevel(1); NextGoaltoLvl += 1000; EXP = 0; 
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: up voted since there was no need for a downvote